# Using conditionals statement over 2 or more conditions in pyrocms

Tags: pyrocms

The only way to ask over 2 conditions in my theme that I think is this:

```
{if '{pyro:url:segments segment="1"}' == 'tos'}
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
{elseif '{pyro:url:segments segment="1"}' == 'privacy'}
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
{/if}
```

I'm nuts? There is a more elegant way to do it??? THX

Answer (score 0):

You can use "OR" within PyroCMS tags:

```
{if '{pyro:url:segments segment="1"}' == 'tos' OR '{pyro:url:segments segment="1"}' == 'privacy'}
     <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
{/if}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks again. I tried something like that but not works: `FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/nginx/pyrocms/system/pyrocms/libraries/Tags.php(541) : eval()'d code on line 5`